# scrolltop will not scroll to the bottom div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop

I'm trying to do this: When you click the button the div will show and you will scroll to the bottom of the page. Other ones are working, just not this one. Does it have something to do with the fact that it's at the bottom of the page?

Here is my js

```
$('#donate').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#seven').show();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#seven').offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: @bjb568 how's that possible?

Comment: @Roko My friend said so. So it's a fundamental law of the universe.

Comment: Daniel, is there anything at all under the last div?  The page can only scroll as low as the very bottom of the page.  If there's no space for it to keep scrolling, it will stop at the bottom of the window

Answer (score 0):

i had the donate id in a href tag and for some reason it didnt work. But made this a button and it all works now

so the html is

```
<button id="donate">Donate</button>
```